# redireccionar vista con @if en laravel

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

estoy intentando que redireccione a una vista en laravel si el usuario cumple con una membresia (membresia=etapa), pero este solo me regresa texto en lugar de la vista, mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
@if (Auth::check())
   @if(Auth::user()->etapa == 1)
   @return view('welcome');
                    @else
                    <a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a>
                        <a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a>
                    @endif

@endif
```

Comment: ?¿, eso esta mal, tu deberias de hacer uso de `@include()` si deseas agregar parte de un html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los re-direccionamientos se deben de hacer en la parte del controlador y no asi en la vista.

```
if (Auth::check()){
   if(Auth::user()->etapa == 1){
      return view('welcome');   
   }
   else{
      return view('otra vista')
   }
}
```

En caso de que desees hacer algo similar en la vista tu debes de **incluir** el html perteneciente, se la puede hacer de varias formas la mas comun y simple es con la funcion `include()`.

```
@if (Auth::check())
   @if(Auth::user()->etapa == 1)
     @include("welcome");
   @else
       <a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a>
       <a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a>
   @endif

@endif
```

Comment: gracias! habia leido algo de eso, mas no se en que parte del controlador, soy nuevo en laravel como podras notar jaja